# Generating multiple R.java and combine them?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm doing custom build, but I'm trying to integrate UnityAds. Unityads has its own resources and hence it generates its own Resources classes **R.java** with its own package. 
My game uses its own resources too, and it generates **R.Java** with it's package name. 
Now the current situation is that I combine all the resources into the game's resources with its package name. 
But the problem is that Unity Ads needs it's own resources.How can I combine them in the build so that each plugin use it's own resources with its package name and not generating conflicts with dex classes?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that UnityAds should be integrated as a separate library project, which means it has its own separate resources. You should not mix your application code/resources with UnityAds' in the same application project.

Please see their [guide](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/Documentation%20for%20Publishers/Integration-Guide-for-Android).

Comment: that's the android guide, its not for Unity